# Is NtQuerySystemInformation for SystemSessionProcessInformation broken on WoW64?

Tags: windows

I have some code that calls `NtQuerySystemInformation` for `SystemProcessInformation`, `SystemExtendedProcessInformation`, and `SystemSessionProcessInformation`. This code does the typical loop checking for `STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH` and resizing the buffer based on the value returned in `ReturnValue`. This works fine for `SystemProcessInformation` and `SystemExtendedProcessInformation`. However, `SystemSessionProcessInformation` is slightly different as the data is retrieved via a secondary buffer in the `SYSTEM_SESSION_PROCESS_INFORMATION` structure. A slightly modified loop mechanism works fine on the native system architecture (32-bit process on 32-bit system or 64-bit process on 64-bit system). However, when running on WoW64 (32-bit process on 64-bit system) if the return status is `STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH` then the value returned in `ReturnLength` is **always** zero. Thus the typical loop mechanism will **not** work, and instead the buffer size must be continually increased until the function returns `STATUS_SUCCESS` (or something other than `STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH`). Is this an oversight on Microsoft's part in the WoW64 layer or am I missing something?  Reproducible code snippet (compile as 32-bit and run on 64-bit system):

```
SYSTEM_SESSION_PROCESS_INFORMATION SessionInfo = { 0 };
SessionInfo.SessionId = 1;
NTSTATUS Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
PVOID Info = NULL;
ULONG InfoLength = 0;
for (;;)
{
    Status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemSessionProcessInformation, &SessionInfo, sizeof(SessionInfo), &InfoLength);
    if (Status != STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
    {
        break;
    }
    // NOTE: InfoLength is always 0 here
    //       only workaround is to continually increase buffer size and try again
    //       e.g. InfoLength += 0x1000
    SessionInfo.Buffer = malloc(InfoLength);
    SessionInfo.SizeOfBuf = InfoLength;
}
```

Comment: In fact, it seems even with the workaround the last process entry is not being 'terminated' with a `NextEntryOffset` value of zero.

Comment: Apparently the WoW64 implementation internally loops until it allocates enough memory to hold the data, figures out that the user-provided buffer is too small to fit the data, then returns the status code without bothering to return a size hint. Brilliant.

Comment: could you email me. I'd like to hire you.